# URLs for deleted questions get SEO'd automatically - is this a security issue?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, deleted-questions, security

When a user visits the link of a deleted questions, he can still see the title in the address bar. For example, when I go to https://stackoverflow.com/q/1, which is a deleted question, it redirects the user to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go, showing the question's title. Is this a (non-critical) security issue?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is really a bug. It's more of a showcase that "you can never truly delete what has been on the Internet", so [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Even if a question is deleted from a Stack Exchange site, it might still be available via the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) which not only stores its title but its entire content, including answers. Also, users with [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can view the question, just as if it weren't deleted (the Help Center link contains some reasons why this is useful).

Note that questions which have been marked as spam, or rude/abusive, such as this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327537 don't have their title restored.